# Wait for object to be available before executing child component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following two components. In parent, I initialize a session. In the child, I access that session. The problem I have is, that session is connecting to slow to a third-party provider. The child component is rendering so fast that session.connected is never valid since it takes a bit longer.

Parent component

```
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
      let connectionCount = 0;
      const session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
      setSession(session);
  }, []);

  // Replace token with your own value:
  session.connect(token, function (error) {
  if (error) {
      console.log("Unable to connect: ", error.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Connected to the session.");
    setSession(session);
  }

  return (
    <OTSessionContext.Provider value={session}>
      {children}
    </OTSessionContext.Provider>
  );
});
```

Child component

```
const Child = ({children}) => {
  const [publisher, setPublisher] = useState();

  const session = useContext(OTSessionContext);
  const publisherProperties = { insertMode: "replace", showControls: false };
  const targetElement = "publisher";

  useEffect(() => {
    const publisher = OT.initPublisher(
      targetElement,
      publisherProperties,
      completionHandler(error, "Publisher initialized.")
    );
    setPublisher(publisher);
  }, []);

  if (session.connected && publisher) {
      publish()
  }

  function publish() {
    if (!session || !publisher) {
      return;
    }

    if (session.capabilities.publish === 1) {
      session.publish(
        publisher,
        completionHandler(error, "Publishing a stream.")
      );
    } else {
      console.log("You cannot publish an audio-video stream.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to find something inside of that Session object that we can use to condition the rendering of the child, like:

```
if (!session.connected) {
  return (<div>Waiting for connection...</div>) // or don't render anything
}

return (
  <OTSessionContext.Provider value={session}>
    {children}
  </OTSessionContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: That literally saved my day. Was trying to solve that all day.